# Splitting the joint probability of 3 random variables

Tags: probability

I want to prove the following equation:
$$p(\theta|X,\alpha) = \frac{p(X|\theta)p(\theta|\alpha)}{p(X|\alpha)}$$

This is used for Beyesian inference (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference#Bayesian_inference)

I can't figure out how to get rid of the joint probability $p(\theta,X,\alpha)$. I see that the formula somehow expresses the joint probability $p(\theta,X,\alpha)$ using the joint probabilities $p(\theta, X), p(\theta, \alpha), p(X,\alpha)$, but I can't find the identity used to achieve this result. Bayes's theorem and the definition of conditional probability gets me nowhere.

Any pointer to the relevant identity/resource would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this is only true under the assumption $P(X|\theta, \alpha) = P(X|\theta)$, i.e. that $X$ is conditionally independent of $\alpha$ given $\theta$. This is fine in Bayesian inference, because we're assuming that $\alpha$ is some meta-parametrisation of $\theta$, and that the distribution of $X$ is completely parametrised by $\theta$.

Anyhoo, assuming the above, and using Bayes' theorem many many times

\begin{align*}
 p(\theta|X, \alpha) &= \frac{p(\theta, X, \alpha)}{p(X,\alpha)} = \frac{p(\theta, X|\alpha)p(\alpha)}{p(X|\alpha)p(\alpha)} \\
&= \frac{p(X|\theta, \alpha) p(\theta|\alpha)}{p(X|\alpha)}\\
&\overset{(a)}{=} \frac{p(X|\theta) p(\theta|\alpha)}{p(X|\alpha)} \\
\end{align*}

Where $(a)$ is due to the assumption above.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation is clear and concise. Thus, in general there is no way to express a joint distribution of three variables as a combination of joint distributions of two variables or less, because such an expression would necessarily imply that some variables are conditionally independent.

Comment: You're welcome. You're right, in general there is no way. 


A bit off topic, but there are some slimy tricks of notation, though. Like calling $(\theta, \alpha)$ one bigger random variable $\eta$, in which case $P_{X, \eta} = P_\eta P_{X|\eta}$. While this isn't very useful in Bayesian information, tricks like this, along with a version of Carathéodory's theorem, are frequently used in network information theory, (in cases where you have a large number of random variables) and lead to some pretty deep results.